# Need to devise a recursive algorithm for the following problem in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

A recursive algorithm that gets an integer n and integer array A as input and check if the given array
A contains two integers, such that n= A[i]+A[j] where A[i] & A[j] can be at any position in array.
  This is what I have come up with

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int arr[],int size,int n)
{
  if (size==1)
    return;
  else
  {
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            if (arr[i]+arr[j]==n)
            {
                cout<<"yes";
                return;
            }
    func(arr,size-1,n);
   }
}

int main()
{
  int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int n = 8;
  func(A,5,n);
  return 0;
}
```

I know it's using recursion but I want a recursive function that avoids all unnecessary iterations. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: "I want a recursive function that avoids all unnecessary iterations" - and how do you figure that recursion will be faster than iteration (assuming that speed is what you are after)? The number of operations you need to perform will be the same regardless of iteration or recursion - in fact, iteration may be faster since you'll avoid function call overhead (unless we're talking tail recursion that the compiler can optimize).

Comment: Your recursion right now seems entirely unnecessary - are you sure you need recursion? If this was me I'd just remove the recursive call...

Comment: i know iteration is easier and better for this problem but my instructor wants recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int arr[],int index,int size,int n)
{

    if(index==size-1)
        return;

  int flag=0;

        for (int j=index+1;j<size;j++)
            if (arr[index]+arr[j]==n)
            {
                flag=1;
                cout<<"yes";
            }

   if(flag==0)
    func(arr,index+1,size,n);
}

int main()
{
  int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int n = 6;
  func(A,0,5,n);
  return 0;
}
```

If you really want a recursive code, this may be one kind of implementation. All i have done is start from 0th index and sum it with every other element and compare it with with 'n'. If it matches fine otherwise make a recursive call with next index(prev index + 1).

Comment: Thanks. I understood your solution. Very well explained!!